# How to get a clean geometry

Tags: edges

[image]An image is attached after making the difference between the two object im not getting a clean geometry. The edges are not sharp. What should i do to get a clean geometry
[image]

Comment: It looks like the geometry is clean, but the view port shading isn't. Try rendering and see if it looks clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The impression of smooth edges is due to enabled Smooth shading. If you wanna to have sharp edges and smooth shading still active, add Edge Split modifier to the object.

Comment: it works perfect

Comment: it work perfect but a small problem when i added a mirror modifier to it and edge is been seen between to objects

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Could you upload an image of this behaviour?

Comment: can u plz tell me how to add my image i have edit the above image and add other or is there any other way to add the image?

Comment: I have added the image. As u can c i got the result as u said adding the edge split modifier but adding a mirror to it i have got the edges rough and i can c the joining edge and some faces also its reversed

Comment: First of all, you should delete faces on the joining side. Second, edge split modifier, in modifiers stack should be after mirror.